# Linq where column == (null reference) not the same as column == null

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I came across a rather strange problem with linq-to-sql. In the following example,

```
var survey = (from s in dbContext.crmc_Surveys
                                   where (s.crmc_Retail_Trade_Id == tradeId) && (s.State_.Equals(state))
                                   select s).First();
```

If tradeId is null, it doesn't behave as if I had specified null specifically like this instead,

```
var survey = (from s in dbContext.crmc_Surveys
                                   where (s.crmc_Retail_Trade_Id == null) && (s.State_.Equals(state))
                                   select s).First();
```

Which is my desired behavior. In fact it doesn't return anything unless both values are non-null. I can't figure out how to accomplish this short of several different linq queries. Any ideas?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Change `where (s.crmc_Retail_Trade_Id == tradeId)` 
to

```
where (s.crmc_Retail_Trade_Id == tradeId || 
      (tradeId == null && s.crmc_Retail_Trade_Id == null))
```

Edit - based on [this post](http://www.brentlamborn.com/post/LINQ-to-SQL-Null-check-in-Where-Clause.aspx) by Brant Lamborn, it looks like the following would do what you want:

```
where (object.Equals(s.crmc_Retail_Trade_Id, tradeId))
```

The [Null Semantics (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882669.aspx) MSDN page links to some interesting info:

> LINQ to SQL does not impose C# null or
>   Visual Basic nothing comparison
>   semantics on SQL. Comparison operators
>   are syntactically translated to their
>   SQL equivalents. The semantics reflect
>   SQL semantics as defined by server or
>   connection settings. Two null values
>   are considered unequal under default
>   SQL Server settings (although you can
>   change the settings to change the
>   semantics). Regardless, LINQ to SQL
>   does not consider server settings in
>   query translation.
>
> A comparison with the literal null
>   (nothing) is translated to the
>   appropriate SQL version (is null or is
>   not null).
>
> The value of null (nothing) in
>   collation is defined by SQL Server;
>   LINQ to SQL does not change the
>   collation.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's the obvious answer. But inquiring minds want to know why a constant null is different than a variable pointing to null.

Comment: I suspect Joel Coehoorn is correct that the second case in your question gets translated to a sql query specifying null directly.

Comment: That seems like a very large flaw or even bug in Microsoft's linq parser to not handle null object references appropriately, but I'll take your words for it.

Comment: "Appropriately" is very subjective - I've added some text from MSDN that explains what LINQ does.

Comment: I just tried the object.Equals workaround, and it works with nullable integers, but not with strings. (Using LINQ to EF, not LINQ to SQL)

Comment: True, when an `nullable int?` appears, LinQ-2-Sql just ignores the whole `where` clause, like it is never there. Instead of explicitly generating `IS NULL` condition.

Answer (score 4):

Another option to solve this, as I ran across this problem as well.

```
where (tradeId == null ? s.crmc_Retail_Trade_Id == null : s.crmc_Retail_Trade_Id == tradeId)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure on this one, but I suspect when linq-to-sql translates that to an sql query string you get a slightly different expression specifying `null` directly such that at some point you end up comparing NULL to itself, and NULL=NULL is defined to be false.

Comment: Unless ANSI_NULLS is set to OFF.  But that causes the universe to implode.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Linq, however in general:

`NULL` represents a missing, unknown, or undefined value. Strictly speaking, a variable cannot equal `NULL`; low-lvel languages which provide this construct usually do so as a convenience because there is no easy alternative -- at a higher level it's usually better to rely on `ISNULL`, `defined`, or whatever features your language supplies.

One undefined variable is not equal to another undefined variable (and the same applies to NULL == NULL). Joe Celko has a good example of writing a query to find all people whose hair colour matches the colour of the vehicle they drive. Should this query match a bald man who walks everywhere?

Comment: I think it's pretty defensible that a man's non-existent hair's color be considered a match to his non-existant car's paint.

Comment: In low level, or high level languages, null is the hex value 0x0 and null == null is true. Now I know this isn't true in SQL but C# is not SQL, we expect this to hold up. Linq-to-Sql is supposed to be an abstraction for C# users. If you ask me MS screwed the pooch, am I wrong?

Comment: Indeed. I was more trying to explain to the inquiring mind that wanted to know why a constant null was different from a variable pointing to one. In most cases null is equivalent to 0x0, a serious problem if you ever needed a pointer to the start of a memory segment (thankfully that's no longer an issue). I say equivalent because I think there is a subtle difference from equal. It's like saying that 1.999999999... is not equal to 2, it's just a mathematical inconvenience that they happen to be the same value.

Comment: I prefer to think they are different. In Perl, 0 is defined. In PHP 0 !== null. In SQL 0 != NULL. In XSLT an attribute set to 0 does not match an undefined attribute. One should keep in mind that even if your language allows it, it's still a test for undefinedness, not equality.

Comment: How it translates from C# to SQL I guess depends on whether it was implemented by a C# guy or an SQL guy. But if it's supposed to be an abstraction for C# programmers and it doesn't do what a C# programmer expects, then MS has indeed screwed the pooch. (Mind you, even if it did work as expected, I'd still suspect there was some pooch-screwing going on somewhere.)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to make sp for this purpose because linq will perform iteration it takes while for your assistance if you are using linq.

```
var c = lstQ_Buffer.Where(q => (((semesterId == 0 || semesterId == null ? q.fkSemesterId == null : q.fkSemesterId == semesterId) && (subjectSpecialtyId == 0 || subjectSpecialtyId == null ? q.fkSubSpecialtyId == null : q.fkSubSpecialtyId == subSpecialtyId) && (subTopicId == 0 || subTopicId == null ? q.fkSubTopicId == null : q.fkSubTopicId == subTopicId)) && (q.fkProgramId == programId && q.fkYearId == yearId && q.fkCourse_ModuleId == courseModuleId && q.fkSubject_SpecialtyId == subjectSpecialtyId && q.fkTopicId == topicId && q.fkDifficultyLevelId == diffucultyLevelId))).ToList();
```