# Linq where clause with DbFunctions.DiffDays and string comparison not working

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq query to get all clients who have invoices which are overdue with more than 30 days.

When i run the query below it does not return any results and if i remove the a.Status it returns the results.

```
var clients = (from a in ClientTable
           join b in Invoices on a.ClientId equals b.InvoiceId
           where DbFunctions.DiffDays(TodayDate, b.InvoiceDueDate) > 30 && a.Status == "Active"
           group a into c by a.id   
           select c).ToList();
```

Please help

Comment: Does the result without the a,Status == "Active" constraint return data with that specified status?

Comment: Yes it does return the results with the active status and all other statuses  including the ones which have a NULL status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the presence of NULL values in the status column where an issue.Resolved it by including object.Equals(customer.Status,"Active") as per this post 
[Handling null values in where clause using LINQ-to-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411894/handling-null-values-in-where-clause-using-linq-to-sql)

```
var clients = (from a in ClientTable
           join b in Invoices on a.ClientId equals b.InvoiceId
           where DbFunctions.DiffDays(TodayDate, b.InvoiceDueDate) > 30 && object.Equals(a.Status,"Active")
           group a into c by a.id   
           select c).ToList();
```