# How to match a NULL column using LINQtoSQL and lambda?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm having a heckuva time trying to match rows where a column is null. I know that in SQL, I have to use the IS keyword to find null columns:

```
SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE ParentCategoryID IS NULL;
```

I'm trying to recreate the above query in LINQtoSQL. I've tried:

```
var RootCats = categoriesRepository.Categories
    .Where(c => c.ParentCategoryID == null);
```

But this doesn't return any records at all. I have found some posts that use a different syntax than what I'm used to in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097539/linq-where-column-null-reference-not-the-same-as-column-null). But I was having difficulty putting that principle into Lambda form.

How do I use LINQtoSQL and Lambda expressions to find rows with null columns?

### Edit

Per question in the comments - ParentCategoryID is an int.

Comment: What data type is ParentCategoryID?

Comment: That should work as is.  I use those kinds of queries all the time.  Have you tried setting the DataContext.Log so you can see what SQL it's emitting?

Comment: Is it a nullable integer? If you remove your where clause, does any of the categories have a ParentCategoryID that is null?

Comment: @Kirk - I'm not sure what you mean when you refer to DataContext.Log.. I'm new to the world of LINQtoSQL :-)

Comment: @Jesper - I know the data in the db has rows with null values in ParentCategoryID. However, I don't think my Data Model is nullable.

Comment: I assume "categoriesRepository" is a LinqToSql DataContext.  That means it has a property called Log that you can assign a writer to so you can inspect all the sql that gets written.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx.  i.e. categoriesRepository.Log = Console.Out;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the ParentCategoryID in your model isn't nullable then it will get the default value of 0 and 0 != null. Open the designer and change the ParentCategoryID so that it is nullable.

Answer (score 0):

To explictly try to force a SQL `IS NULL`, try something like this,

```
int? foo=null;
var RootCats = categoriesRepository.Categories
    .Where(c => c.ParentCategoryID == foo );
```

In my test code, [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/CodeSnippetIDE.aspx) shows the resultant SQL as: `WHERE [t0].[ParentID] IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Per Jesper's questioning I made Category.ParentCategoryID a nullable int and all works well!

Comment: FWIW, you can do the opposite when you've an inherently nullable type (i.e. a reference type, of which string is the most common case) by describing it as `CanBeNull=false` in the `Column` attribute. This prevents checks against null, for queries that are more efficient and, perhaps more importantly, often clearer to read when you are debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently discovered that using object.equals(myobj, null) works for this, and can be included in the lambda itself so is rather neat.