# Force equality operator when comparing to null in NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate

NHibernate is clever when it comes to comparing fields to null. Consider the following LINQ statement:

```
string s = null;
var rows = session.Query<Entity>
  .Where(e => e.SomeField == s)
  .ToList();
```

The statement is transformed into the SQL query

```
SELECT ...
FROM entity_table
WHERE some_field IS NULL;
```

In some cases I don't want this behavior. I want the resulting query to contain the `some_field = NULL` restriction (which is never true).

(How) can I instruct NHibernate to do this? Or do I have to write two queries and handle the null-case explicitly in code?

Note that this is in the context of NHibernate, not linq-to-sql. NHibernate cannot transform `object.Equals(e.SomeField, s)` into an SQL query. Also, comparing to a variable which is currently `null` and comparing to the `null` keyword directly will yield the same query with NHibernate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq where column == (null reference) not the same as column == null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097539/linq-where-column-null-reference-not-the-same-as-column-null)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QueryOver`, but will generate parameterized query:

```cs
string s = null;

var rows = session.QueryOver<Entity>()
    .Where(Expression.Eq(Projections.Property<Entity>(x => x.SomeField), s))
    .List();
```