# Query Nullable Column Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a `Nullable` `BIGINT` field in the database table.

I am using `linq` to `sql` to retrieve data from that table in c#.

> c.ExtensionID == (ExtensionId == 0 ? (long?)null : ExtensionId)

The above piece of code is what i am using currently, but it does not return me the rows with null in `ExtensionID` Column.

but if i use it like `c.ExtensionID == null` then it will return records.

Below is the full linq to sql code.

```
var q = (from c in dbContext.Investments
         join cd in dbContext.ContractContractorDetails
         on c.ContractContractorId equals cd.ID
         join cc in dbContext.ContractorCategories
         on c.ContractorCategory equals cc.ID
         join ic in dbContext.InvestmentCategories
         on c.InvestmentCategory equals ic.ID
         where c.InvestmentClassificationType == type && cd.ContractId.Equals(ContractID) && c.Phase == phase && c.ExtensionID == (ExtensionId == 0 ? (long?)null : ExtensionId)
         select new
         {
             ID = c.ID,
             Year = c.Year,
             ContractorCategory = c.ContractorCategory,
             ContractorCategoryName = cc.Name,
             CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
             InvestmentCategory = c.InvestmentCategory,
             InvestmentCategoryName = ic.Name,
             Summary = c.Summary,
             IsContractRelated = c.IsContractRelated,
             InvestmentAmount = c.InvestmentAmount,
             Phase = c.Phase,
             InvestmentClassificationType = c.InvestmentClassificationType,
             ContractContractorId = c.ContractContractorId,
             CreatedBy = c.CreatedBy,
             LastUpdatedOn = c.LastUpdatedOn,
             LastUpdatedBy = c.LastUpdatedBy,
             Period=c.Period,
             ExtensionId = c.ExtensionID
         }).ToList();
```

Comment: perhaps `ExtensionId ` is never `0`. Do you check `ExtensionId =0` ?

Comment: yes i checked, it did not return me any rows.

Comment: Do you sure has data in database for `ExtensionID=null` ?

Comment: yes, ExtensionID has null values in the db

Comment: @Eldeniz but if i use it like c.ExtensionID == null then it will return records.

Comment: This senseless. Can you check  `c.ExtensionID == (ExtensionId == 0 ? null : ExtensionId)`?

Comment: no luck , still the same

Comment: Can you check  `ExtensionId` value with debug?

Comment: ExtensionId  = 0 , when i debug , database column has null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the problem solved using the below code.

```
object.Equals(c.ExtensionID, (ExtensionId == 0 ? null : ExtensionId))
```

with the help of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097539/linq-where-column-null-reference-not-the-same-as-column-null)