# LINQ query with variable that may or maynot be null does not return results when null

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query with a WHERE clause that has a variable that sometimes will be NULL. When this variable is NULL I can not get it to pull any results even though there are results to be taken. I found [Linq where column == (null reference) not the same as column == null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097539/linq-where-column-null-reference-not-the-same-as-column-null) and tried the solutions provided there with no success. What am I doing wrong?

```
public async Task<List<SectionNavigationMenuDTO>> GetSectionNavigationMenu(int? SectionID, bool IsAdmin = false)
{
    return await _siteDbContext.SectionNavigationMenuItems
        //.Where(snmi => snmi.SectionID == SectionID && snmi.IsAdminOnly == IsAdmin) //No results at all
        //.Where(snmi => object.Equals(snmi.SectionID, SectionID)) //No results at all
        //.Where(snmi => (snmi.SectionID == SectionID ||  (SectionID == null &&  snmi.SectionID == null))) //No results at all
        //.Where(snmi => snmi.IsAdminOnly == IsAdmin) //Returns 3 results
       .OrderBy(snmi => snmi.Name)
       .Select(sni => new SectionNavigationMenuDTO()
       {
           Name = sni.Name,
           URL = sni.URL
       })
       .ToListAsync();
}
```

Edit:

The `SectionID` should be either filled with a `int` or `null` and be valid in both cases. If the `SectionID` variable is `NULL` then it should pass `NULL` as the argument in for the LINQ query. The database does contain entries with `NULL` for the `SectionID` and the query `SELECT * FROM dbo.SectionNavigationMenuItems WHERE SectionID IS NULL` does return 3 results as expected.

The top commented `WHERE` clause is what I want to happen (with the two comparisons) the other 3 are what I have tried to get this to work and the results.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the value of the *argument* `SectionID` is null? Should there be no comparison at all? Is the schema for the table set to be nullable? Are there null values in the table? There is much in this question that we can only guess at. You need to provide an [mcve] if you want further help.

Comment: @Igor I have edited the question to address your questions I hope.

Comment: Null translation should happen automatically for you, there is no need to do anything special. If `null` is passed in as an argument then `.Where(snmi => snmi.SectionID == SectionID)` would roughly be translate as `WHERE (snmi.SectionID IS NULL AND @sectionId IS NULL) OR (snmi.SectionID = @sectionId))`. I would capture the executed query either in code at runtime or using your DBMS tool to see what is executed and then compare the results.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete in addition to what Igor said. You are passing `IsAdmin` in method paramether, but in the query you're comparing that to `IsAdminOnly` so logic should be a little different.
Does `SELECT * FROM dbo.SectionNavigationMenuItems WHERE SectionID IS NULL AND IsAdminOnly = flase` also returns 3 records?

Comment: I don't have a DBMS tool installed as to do direct querys I use the Azure DB interface in my online portal. I will look into getting one for the feature. As the IsAdminOnly that is a bool field in the DB. If I add the `IsAdminOnly = true` to the query it returns the expected 3 reaults (note. I use tried in the query vs the false you sugges as the entries are true in the DB and using the debuger in VS as well as just the last where clause I did confirm the value of true was being passed into that veriable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public async Task<List<SectionNavigationMenuDTO>> GetSectionNavigationMenu(int? SectionID, bool IsAdmin = false)
{
    return await _siteDbContext.SectionNavigationMenuItems           
        .Where(snmi => snmi.IsAdminOnly == IsAdmin && (SectionID==null || SectionID==smi.SectionID ) ) 
        .OrderBy(snmi => snmi.Name)
        .Select(sni => new SectionNavigationMenuDTO()
        {
            Name = sni.Name,
            URL = sni.URL
        })
        .ToListAsync();
}
```